# Installing Pyside2 with qmake: "QT version 5.7+ required", but I have version 5.11 installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qmake, pyside2

I'm trying to install pyside2 and following the steps of the [Pyside2 website](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_GettingStarted/MacOS). After executing the following step:

```
$ python setup.py build --qmake=/anaconda3/bin/qmake --build-tests --ignore-git --jobs=8
```

I get the the following error message :

```
running build
Removing /Users/mymac/pyside-setup/pyside_package
Python architecture is 64bit
Incompatible Qt version detected: 5.6.2. A Qt version >= 5.7 is required.
```

I don't understand given the fact that i have `qt 5.10` installed:

```
$ brew list --versions qt5
qt 5.10.1
```

Comment: But what version of qt is anaconda3 using?

Comment: Thank you very much @ekhumoro. Indeed, I have 2 places where qt is installed on my computer: `/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-5.6.2-h9975529_14` and `/Users/mymac/Qt/5.11.0`. And the version on of anaconda3 is indeed 5.6. I tried then `conda install -c anaconda qt` but it reinstalled the `qt.5.6.2`. Any idea of what I should do?

Comment: Just found that github page: `https://github.com/conda-forge/qt-feedstock/issues/53` which says that indeed there is no supported version of qt beyond version 5.6. The question is should then Pyside2 by run on python without running it through Conda. If yes, is possible (and advisable) to have 2 version of python on the same computer, and if yes, how should I proceed?

Comment: I don't know much about anaconda or mac, so I can't really comment.

Answer (score 0):

I could install pyside2 using this [github page](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels/issues/95).

I ran the following lines:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pyside2
```

and it worked!!

Many thanks to @fredrikaverpil